# How do I replace one word for another in JS?

Tags: javascript, function, replace

I am attempting to replace the word 'and' with 'dog', using JavaScript. Here is my code:

```
var magic = document.getElementById("magic");
function myFunction() {
    magic.innerHTML.replace('and', 'dog');
}
myFunction;
```

Comment: And aside from not actually calling your function, what problem are you having?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var magic = document.getElementById("magic");
function myFunction() {
    magic.innerHTML = magic.innerHTML.replace('and', 'dog');
}
myFunction();
```

Answer (score 4):

`replace` does not change the input, it *returns* the changed value – so you have to assign it to `magic.innerHTML` again.

Comment: Just out of curiosity--why doesn't it change the input?

Comment: Because it actually _can’t_ – Strings are “immutable” in JavaScript, and since for example `"foobar".replace("bar", "baz")` is a perfectly valid way of calling `replace` on a String value, it _can_ only _return_ the changed value.